# Why is Order of files different in file explorer and in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

[image: Difference in file Arrangement (Photo)]

This folder has Approximately 57k such files. And If you look at the Right image, You can see the file order being something like outputfile_11,12,13 n so on But in the left image being outputfile_11,110,1100,11000

Why is it so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explorer implements "natural" sorting by parsing numbers in file names. PowerShell uses alphabetical order.